# How to have multiple iterable directories in Jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

In Jekyll, posts are written and stored in `_posts` directory.

Part of the Jekyll tutorial to create an index of posts is:

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What I want is to have another directory with text files and be able to create an "index" like the one for the posts. The fields I need are `title` and `content`.

The reason why I don't want to use `posts` is because I am already using them.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can !

Two options : [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) or [page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/)

Both can have a `title` variable in the front matter, and a `content`.

### Collections

Once you've setup you collection (eg : mycollection), you just generate you index with :

```
<ul>
{% for item in site.mycollection %}
  <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

### pages

You can use pages that you can sort with a custom variable in front matter like :

```
---
title: my page
mycustomvar: true
---
```

By doing `{% assign custompages = site.pages | where: "mycustomvar", true %}` you get an array of pages containing your custom variable set to true.

You then just have to loop in this array to generate you index :

```
{% assign custompages = site.pages | where: "mycustomvar", true %}
<ul>
{% for item in custompages %}
  <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. I also reached to the same answer after some research. Can you add the part on how to create a collection, then I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Yo! You can read the doc about collections here : http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/